# excel vba to add data when matched

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a match of values from sheet 10 which loops from 2 to 11000
looking for a match in in column A of sheet 10 with column A of sheet3. Then if matched copy value from column B sheet 3 to column F of sheet10 , my code below works , but it takes 25 mins to run. Is there a quicker way to run this please

```
Sub update_OpGroup()
Dim lastrow10, lastrow3
lastrow10 = Sheet10.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow3 = Sheet3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim x, y, b
b = 2
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
For x = 1 To lastrow10
For y = 2 To lastrow3
If Sheet10.Range("A" & x).Value = Sheet3.Range("A" & y).Value Then Sheet10.Range("F" & x).Value = Sheet3.Range("B" & y).Value:  GoTo foundit
Next y
foundit:
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Find()` method of `Range` object:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim found As Range
For x = 1 To lastrow10
    Set found = Sheet3.Range("A2:A" & lastrow3).Find(what:=Sheet10.Range("A" & x).Value, lookat:=xlValues, LookIn:=xlWhole)
    If Not found Is Nothing Then Sheet10.Range("F" & x).Value = Sheet3.Range("B" & found.Row).Value
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this , I tried to run your code , but it comes up with an object variable or not set error

Comment: Set found = Sheet3.Range("A2:A" & lastrow3).Find(what:=Sheet10.Range("A" & x).Value, lookat:=xlValues, LookIn:=xlWhole)   is highlighted yellow

Comment: I only showed the part of your code to be changed. the rest of your code (both preceding and following it) must be in place!

Comment: When hitting error, click”Debug” on the error message box, jump to Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it out), type (omit the outer quotation marks) “?Sheet3.Range("A2:A" & lastrow3).Address”, press return and see the outcome

Comment: it comes up with invalid use of property

Answer (score 0):

I believe an INDEX/MATCH formula may fulfill your needs much quicker than VBA copy/paste.

If the range in column A is always fixed, the below formula works:
=INDEX(Sheet3!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet10!$A:$A,Sheet3!$A:$A,0),1)

If the range is varied, the below VBA should cover it:

```
Sub Fill_Formula()

Dim lRow As String

        lRow = Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("A:A").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("F2").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Sheet3!C2,MATCH(Sheet10!C1,Sheet3!C1,0),1)"
            Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("F2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("F2:F" & lRow), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

If a formula isn't acceptable in the cells you could add:

```
Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("F2:F" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```